# Use .htaccess to convert user ID's to usernames?

Tags: htaccess, php, url-rewriting

I want to use .htaccess to convert the urls that link to profile pages from an ID number to a name. For example, on Facebook, if you were to go to:

```
https://facebook.com/profile.php?id=4
```

It would take you to Mark Zuckerberg's profile page. However, you can also simply go to:

```
https://facebook.com/zuck
```

...which is more user friendly and easier to remember. How can I use htaccess to convert an id number to a username? Do I need to send it to a php script to process and send back the name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As well as storing a unique ID you'd want to store a unique (let's call it) URL for each user too.  Or generate one when your user accounts are created.  Then you can do a regular re-write rule something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^/([^/\.]+)/?$ /display-account.htm?account=$1 [NC,L]
```

Then write your display-account.htm page to grab the account URL parm and pull data from your database with it.

I use pretty much this exact method for some web apps that I've built.  It works pretty flawlessly.